# Split XML file into multiple files using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am having trouble splitting an XML file into multiple files using XSLT.

I've tried splitting the file based on the attached XSLT code.  I've succeeded in getting the file to split.  However, I haven't been able to figure out how to replicate the file and create one for each  in the original file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//FlightGroup">
<xsl:variable 
    name="filehandle"
    select="//Info/Campaign/CampaignNumber"/>
<xsl:variable
    name="FlightGroupId"
    select="FlightGroup-id"
    />
<xsl:variable name="filename"
  select="concat('file:///c:/Temp/',$filehandle,'_',$FlightGroupId,'.xml')" />
<xsl:value-of select="$filename" />   <!-- Creating  -->
<xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xml">
    <Data>
        <filename><xsl:value-of select = "concat($filehandle, '_', $FlightGroupId)"/></filename>
        <xsl:copy-of select = "//OrderCustomers" />
        <xsl:copy-of select = "//Campaign"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select = "." />
    </Data>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to be able to generate one file for each flight group with the rest of the file being a duplicate of the original.

For example:

Source File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Info>
    <OrderCustomers>
      <OrderCustomer>
        <IsPrimaryOrderer>true</IsPrimaryOrderer>
        <IsPrimaryPayor>true</IsPrimaryPayor>
        <Customer>
          <account-number>20007658</account-number>
          <accountid>7659</accountid>
          <Name1>DIGITAL TEST ACCOUNT</Name1>
          <Phone>0000000000</Phone>
          <Type-id>2</Type-id>
          <Type>Commercial</Type>
          <Company-id>1</Company-id>
          <Company>Company1</Company>
          <Address>
            <Addr1>123 Main</Addr1>
            <City>Anytown</City>
            <Postal-Code>99999</Postal-Code>
            <Country-id>1</Country-id>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <State-id>113</State-id>
            <State>TX</State>
          </Address>
          <PrimarySalesRep>Rep1</PrimarySalesRep>
          <Category>Local</Category>
          <PaymentMethod-id>4</PaymentMethod-id>
          <PaymentMethod>Credit Card</PaymentMethod>
        </Customer>
      </OrderCustomer>
    </OrderCustomers>
    <ad-ordered-by>test</ad-ordered-by>
    <publication-code>Y</publication-code>
    <pagination-code>N</pagination-code>
    <ProductionCode>N</ProductionCode>
    <ad-sold-by-id>113</ad-sold-by-id>
    <ad-sold-by>Rep1</ad-sold-by>
    <ad-sold-by-name>National</ad-sold-by-name>
    <ad-order-taker-id>15</ad-order-taker-id>
    <ad-order-taker>jsmith</ad-order-taker>
    <CreateDate>07022019 13:50:31</CreateDate>
    <LastEditDate>07022019 13:50:33</LastEditDate>
    <LastEditUser>jsmith</LastEditUser>
    <order-number>00000994</order-number>
    <price>10.00</price>
    <company-id>1</company-id>
    <company>Company1</company>
    <CreationDate>070220191350</CreationDate>
    <Campaign>
      <CampaignId>205</CampaignId>
      <CampaignNumber>00994-01</CampaignNumber>
      <Name>DIGITAL TEST ACCOUNT01</Name>
      <Type-id>1</Type-id>
      <Type>Banner</Type>
      <Category-id>1</Category-id>
      <Category>Standard</Category>
      <StartDate>07072019</StartDate>
      <EndDate>07312019</EndDate>
      <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
      <Price>10.00</Price>
      <CampaignUnit>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <Name>300x250</Name>
        <Width>300</Width>
        <Height>250</Height>
      </CampaignUnit>
      <CampaignUnit>
        <Id>6</Id>
        <Name>728x90</Name>
        <Width>728</Width>
        <Height>90</Height>
      </CampaignUnit>
      <FlightGroup>
        <Name>Group1</Name>
        <FlightGroup-id>296</FlightGroup-id>
        <CampaignUnit-id>7</CampaignUnit-id>
        <CampaignUnit>300x250</CampaignUnit>
        <Quantity>500</Quantity>
        <StartDate>07072019</StartDate>
        <EndDate>07312019</EndDate>
        <Flight>
          <Flight-id>666</Flight-id>
          <Site-id>2</Site-id>
          <NetworkId>3</NetworkId>
          <Network>Digital</Network>
          <Site>anysite.com</Site>
          <Section-id>20</Section-id>
          <Section>Business</Section>
          <Page-id>3</Page-id>
          <Page>ATF</Page>
          <SiteURL>www.anysite.com</SiteURL>
          <InvoicedAlreadyFlag>0</InvoicedAlreadyFlag>
          <PublishedFlag>true</PublishedFlag>
          <Price>2.50</Price>
          <Quantity>250</Quantity>
          <dates>
            <date Insertion-id="26901" PublishedFlag="true">07072019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26902" PublishedFlag="true">07082019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26903" PublishedFlag="true">07092019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26904" PublishedFlag="true">07102019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26905" PublishedFlag="true">07112019</date>
          </dates>
        </Flight>
        <Flight>
          <Flight-id>667</Flight-id>
          <Site-id>2</Site-id>
          <NetworkId>3</NetworkId>
          <Network>Digital</Network>
          <Site>anysite.com</Site>
          <Section-id>20</Section-id>
          <Section>Business</Section>
          <Page-id>4</Page-id>
          <Page>BTF</Page>
          <SiteURL>www.anysite.com</SiteURL>
          <Quantity>250</Quantity>
          <dates>
            <date Insertion-id="26926" PublishedFlag="true">07072019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26927" PublishedFlag="true">07082019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26928" PublishedFlag="true">07092019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26929" PublishedFlag="true">07102019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26930" PublishedFlag="true">07112019</date>
          </dates>
        </Flight>
      </FlightGroup>
      <FlightGroup>
        <Name>Group2</Name>
        <FlightGroup-id>297</FlightGroup-id>
        <CampaignUnit-id>6</CampaignUnit-id>
        <CampaignUnit>728x90</CampaignUnit>
        <Quantity>500</Quantity>
        <StartDate>07072019</StartDate>
        <EndDate>07312019</EndDate>
        <Flight>
          <Flight-id>668</Flight-id>
          <Site-id>2</Site-id>
          <NetworkId>3</NetworkId>
          <Network>Digital</Network>
          <Site>anysite.com</Site>
          <Section-id>20</Section-id>
          <Section>Business</Section>
          <Page-id>3</Page-id>
          <Page>ATF</Page>
          <SiteURL>www.anysite.com</SiteURL>
          <Quantity>250</Quantity>
          <dates>
            <date Insertion-id="26951" PublishedFlag="true">07072019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26952" PublishedFlag="true">07082019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26953" PublishedFlag="true">07092019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26954" PublishedFlag="true">07102019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26955" PublishedFlag="true">07112019</date>
          </dates>
        </Flight>
        <Flight>
          <Flight-id>669</Flight-id>
          <Site-id>2</Site-id>
          <NetworkId>3</NetworkId>
          <Network>Digital</Network>
          <Site>anysite.com</Site>
          <Section-id>20</Section-id>
          <Section>Business</Section>
          <Page-id>4</Page-id>
          <Page>BTF</Page>
          <SiteURL>www.anysite.com</SiteURL>
          <Quantity>250</Quantity>
          <dates>
            <date Insertion-id="26976" PublishedFlag="true">07072019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26977" PublishedFlag="true">07082019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26978" PublishedFlag="true">07092019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26979" PublishedFlag="true">07102019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26980" PublishedFlag="true">07112019</date>
          </dates>
        </Flight>
      </FlightGroup>
      <FrequencyCap />
      <AdServingId>3</AdServingId>
      <AdServing>DFP</AdServing>
      <CampaignViewTypeId>2</CampaignViewTypeId>
      <CampaignViewType>Impressions</CampaignViewType>
      <CreateDate>07022019 13:50:31</CreateDate>
      <CreateUser>Rep1</CreateUser>
      <LastEditDate>07022019 13:50:33</LastEditDate>
      <LastEditUser>Rep1</LastEditUser>
    </Campaign>
    <Company>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <COMPANYCODE>Company1</COMPANYCODE>
    </Company>
  </Info>
</Data>
```

File #1 - 00994-01_296.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Info>
    <OrderCustomers>
      <OrderCustomer>
        <IsPrimaryOrderer>true</IsPrimaryOrderer>
        <IsPrimaryPayor>true</IsPrimaryPayor>
        <Customer>
          <account-number>20007658</account-number>
          <accountid>7659</accountid>
          <Name1>DIGITAL TEST ACCOUNT</Name1>
          <Phone>0000000000</Phone>
          <Type-id>2</Type-id>
          <Type>Commercial</Type>
          <Company-id>1</Company-id>
          <Company>Company1</Company>
          <Address>
            <Addr1>123 Main</Addr1>
            <City>Anytown</City>
            <Postal-Code>99999</Postal-Code>
            <Country-id>1</Country-id>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <State-id>113</State-id>
            <State>TX</State>
          </Address>
          <PrimarySalesRep>Rep1</PrimarySalesRep>
          <Category>Local</Category>
          <PaymentMethod-id>4</PaymentMethod-id>
          <PaymentMethod>Credit Card</PaymentMethod>
        </Customer>
      </OrderCustomer>
    </OrderCustomers>
    <ad-ordered-by>test</ad-ordered-by>
    <publication-code>Y</publication-code>
    <pagination-code>N</pagination-code>
    <ProductionCode>N</ProductionCode>
    <ad-sold-by-id>113</ad-sold-by-id>
    <ad-sold-by>Rep1</ad-sold-by>
    <ad-sold-by-name>National</ad-sold-by-name>
    <ad-order-taker-id>15</ad-order-taker-id>
    <ad-order-taker>jsmith</ad-order-taker>
    <CreateDate>07022019 13:50:31</CreateDate>
    <LastEditDate>07022019 13:50:33</LastEditDate>
    <LastEditUser>jsmith</LastEditUser>
    <order-number>00000994</order-number>
    <price>10.00</price>
    <company-id>1</company-id>
    <company>Company1</company>
    <CreationDate>070220191350</CreationDate>
    <Campaign>
      <CampaignId>205</CampaignId>
      <CampaignNumber>00994-01</CampaignNumber>
      <Name>DIGITAL TEST ACCOUNT01</Name>
      <Type-id>1</Type-id>
      <Type>Banner</Type>
      <Category-id>1</Category-id>
      <Category>Standard</Category>
      <StartDate>07072019</StartDate>
      <EndDate>07312019</EndDate>
      <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
      <Price>10.00</Price>
      <CampaignUnit>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <Name>300x250</Name>
        <Width>300</Width>
        <Height>250</Height>
      </CampaignUnit>
      <CampaignUnit>
        <Id>6</Id>
        <Name>728x90</Name>
        <Width>728</Width>
        <Height>90</Height>
      </CampaignUnit>
      <FlightGroup>
        <Name>Group1</Name>
        <FlightGroup-id>296</FlightGroup-id>
        <CampaignUnit-id>7</CampaignUnit-id>
        <CampaignUnit>300x250</CampaignUnit>
        <Quantity>500</Quantity>
        <StartDate>07072019</StartDate>
        <EndDate>07312019</EndDate>
        <Flight>
          <Flight-id>666</Flight-id>
          <Site-id>2</Site-id>
          <NetworkId>3</NetworkId>
          <Network>Digital</Network>
          <Site>anysite.com</Site>
          <Section-id>20</Section-id>
          <Section>Business</Section>
          <Page-id>3</Page-id>
          <Page>ATF</Page>
          <SiteURL>www.anysite.com</SiteURL>
          <InvoicedAlreadyFlag>0</InvoicedAlreadyFlag>
          <PublishedFlag>true</PublishedFlag>
          <Price>2.50</Price>
          <Quantity>250</Quantity>
          <dates>
            <date Insertion-id="26901" PublishedFlag="true">07072019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26902" PublishedFlag="true">07082019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26903" PublishedFlag="true">07092019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26904" PublishedFlag="true">07102019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26905" PublishedFlag="true">07112019</date>
          </dates>
        </Flight>
        <Flight>
          <Flight-id>667</Flight-id>
          <Site-id>2</Site-id>
          <NetworkId>3</NetworkId>
          <Network>Digital</Network>
          <Site>anysite.com</Site>
          <Section-id>20</Section-id>
          <Section>Business</Section>
          <Page-id>4</Page-id>
          <Page>BTF</Page>
          <SiteURL>www.anysite.com</SiteURL>
          <Quantity>250</Quantity>
          <dates>
            <date Insertion-id="26926" PublishedFlag="true">07072019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26927" PublishedFlag="true">07082019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26928" PublishedFlag="true">07092019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26929" PublishedFlag="true">07102019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26930" PublishedFlag="true">07112019</date>
          </dates>
        </Flight>
      </FlightGroup>
      <FrequencyCap />
      <AdServingId>3</AdServingId>
      <AdServing>DFP</AdServing>
      <CampaignViewTypeId>2</CampaignViewTypeId>
      <CampaignViewType>Impressions</CampaignViewType>
      <CreateDate>07022019 13:50:31</CreateDate>
      <CreateUser>Rep1</CreateUser>
      <LastEditDate>07022019 13:50:33</LastEditDate>
      <LastEditUser>Rep1</LastEditUser>
    </Campaign>
    <Company>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <COMPANYCODE>Company1</COMPANYCODE>
    </Company>
  </Info>
</Data>
```

File #2 - 00994-01_297.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Info>
    <OrderCustomers>
      <OrderCustomer>
        <IsPrimaryOrderer>true</IsPrimaryOrderer>
        <IsPrimaryPayor>true</IsPrimaryPayor>
        <Customer>
          <account-number>20007658</account-number>
          <accountid>7659</accountid>
          <Name1>DIGITAL TEST ACCOUNT</Name1>
          <Phone>0000000000</Phone>
          <Type-id>2</Type-id>
          <Type>Commercial</Type>
          <Company-id>1</Company-id>
          <Company>Company1</Company>
          <Address>
            <Addr1>123 Main</Addr1>
            <City>Anytown</City>
            <Postal-Code>99999</Postal-Code>
            <Country-id>1</Country-id>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <State-id>113</State-id>
            <State>TX</State>
          </Address>
          <PrimarySalesRep>Rep1</PrimarySalesRep>
          <Category>Local</Category>
          <PaymentMethod-id>4</PaymentMethod-id>
          <PaymentMethod>Credit Card</PaymentMethod>
        </Customer>
      </OrderCustomer>
    </OrderCustomers>
    <ad-ordered-by>test</ad-ordered-by>
    <publication-code>Y</publication-code>
    <pagination-code>N</pagination-code>
    <ProductionCode>N</ProductionCode>
    <ad-sold-by-id>113</ad-sold-by-id>
    <ad-sold-by>Rep1</ad-sold-by>
    <ad-sold-by-name>National</ad-sold-by-name>
    <ad-order-taker-id>15</ad-order-taker-id>
    <ad-order-taker>jsmith</ad-order-taker>
    <CreateDate>07022019 13:50:31</CreateDate>
    <LastEditDate>07022019 13:50:33</LastEditDate>
    <LastEditUser>jsmith</LastEditUser>
    <order-number>00000994</order-number>
    <price>10.00</price>
    <company-id>1</company-id>
    <company>Company1</company>
    <CreationDate>070220191350</CreationDate>
    <Campaign>
      <CampaignId>205</CampaignId>
      <CampaignNumber>00994-01</CampaignNumber>
      <Name>DIGITAL TEST ACCOUNT01</Name>
      <Type-id>1</Type-id>
      <Type>Banner</Type>
      <Category-id>1</Category-id>
      <Category>Standard</Category>
      <StartDate>07072019</StartDate>
      <EndDate>07312019</EndDate>
      <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
      <Price>10.00</Price>
      <CampaignUnit>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <Name>300x250</Name>
        <Width>300</Width>
        <Height>250</Height>
      </CampaignUnit>
      <CampaignUnit>
        <Id>6</Id>
        <Name>728x90</Name>
        <Width>728</Width>
        <Height>90</Height>
      </CampaignUnit>
      <FlightGroup>
        <Name>Group2</Name>
        <FlightGroup-id>297</FlightGroup-id>
        <CampaignUnit-id>6</CampaignUnit-id>
        <CampaignUnit>728x90</CampaignUnit>
        <Quantity>500</Quantity>
        <StartDate>07072019</StartDate>
        <EndDate>07312019</EndDate>
        <Flight>
          <Flight-id>668</Flight-id>
          <Site-id>2</Site-id>
          <NetworkId>3</NetworkId>
          <Network>Digital</Network>
          <Site>anysite.com</Site>
          <Section-id>20</Section-id>
          <Section>Business</Section>
          <Page-id>3</Page-id>
          <Page>ATF</Page>
          <SiteURL>www.anysite.com</SiteURL>
          <Quantity>250</Quantity>
          <dates>
            <date Insertion-id="26951" PublishedFlag="true">07072019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26952" PublishedFlag="true">07082019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26953" PublishedFlag="true">07092019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26954" PublishedFlag="true">07102019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26955" PublishedFlag="true">07112019</date>
          </dates>
        </Flight>
        <Flight>
          <Flight-id>669</Flight-id>
          <Site-id>2</Site-id>
          <NetworkId>3</NetworkId>
          <Network>Digital</Network>
          <Site>anysite.com</Site>
          <Section-id>20</Section-id>
          <Section>Business</Section>
          <Page-id>4</Page-id>
          <Page>BTF</Page>
          <SiteURL>www.anysite.com</SiteURL>
          <Quantity>250</Quantity>
          <dates>
            <date Insertion-id="26976" PublishedFlag="true">07072019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26977" PublishedFlag="true">07082019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26978" PublishedFlag="true">07092019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26979" PublishedFlag="true">07102019</date>
            <date Insertion-id="26980" PublishedFlag="true">07112019</date>
          </dates>
        </Flight>
      </FlightGroup>
      <FrequencyCap />
      <AdServingId>3</AdServingId>
      <AdServing>DFP</AdServing>
      <CampaignViewTypeId>2</CampaignViewTypeId>
      <CampaignViewType>Impressions</CampaignViewType>
      <CreateDate>07022019 13:50:31</CreateDate>
      <CreateUser>Rep1</CreateUser>
      <LastEditDate>07022019 13:50:33</LastEditDate>
      <LastEditUser>Rep1</LastEditUser>
    </Campaign>
    <Company>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <COMPANYCODE>Company1</COMPANYCODE>
    </Company>
  </Info>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I need to be able to generate one file for each flight group with the rest of the file being a duplicate of the original.": Then using an approach like

```
<xsl:template match="FlightGroup">
  <xsl:result-document href="{/Info/Campaign/CampaignNumber}-{FlightGroup-id}.xml">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="split">
         <xsl:with-param name="this-flight-group" select="." tunnel="yes"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="split">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FlightGroup" mode="split">
  <xsl:param name="this-flight-group" tunnel="yes"/>
  <xsl:if test=". is $this-flight-group">
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

should do. It sets up a template for `FlightGroup` elements in the unnamed default mode and creates the result document, then it pushes the whole document through the mode named `split`, storing the current `FlightGroup` element in a tunnel parameter. The mode is set up to use the identity transformation as a base processing and on matching `FlightGroup` elements it has a template comparing the tunnel parameter to the currently processed `FlightGroup` based on node identity with the `is` operator, in case of identity it just delegates processing with `xsl:next-match` to the identity transformation, otherwise it does no further processing of any `FlightGroup` in that mode.

Using XSLT 3 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 and later (all editions) and Altova XML 2017 R3 and later) and the new features of shadow attributes and static parameters one could even try to write a generic solution that takes the "split" pattern and the "file name" expression as static parameters, with that idea the above would be implemented as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:param name="split-pattern" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'FlightGroup'"/>

    <xsl:param name="file-name-expression" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'{//Info/Campaign/CampaignNumber}-{FlightGroup-id}.xml'"/>

    <xsl:template _match="{$split-pattern}">
        <xsl:result-document _href="{$file-name-expression}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="split">
                <xsl:with-param name="this-split-element" select="." tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode name="split" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template _match="{$split-pattern}" mode="split">
        <xsl:param name="this-split-element" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:if test=". is $this-split-element">
            <xsl:next-match/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and anyone wanting to split on a certain element (e.g. `foo`) with a certain file name expression (e.g. the static string `split` plus the child selection `id`) could simply adapt the static parameters e.g. done below inline

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:param name="split-pattern" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'foo'"/>

    <xsl:param name="file-name-expression" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'split-{id}.xml'"/>

    <xsl:template _match="{$split-pattern}">
        <xsl:result-document _href="{$file-name-expression}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="split">
                <xsl:with-param name="this-split-element" select="." tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode name="split" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template _match="{$split-pattern}" mode="split">
        <xsl:param name="this-split-element" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:if test=". is $this-split-element">
            <xsl:next-match/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but of course XSLT 3 processors or IDEs allow you to set static parameters without even touching/changing the XSLT code itself.

Comment: Martin - after a modification to direct the resulting documents to a folder, this worked great.  What kind of black magic is this??!?!

Comment: @geektampa, I have added a paragraph explaining the approach, it is basically just using modes, the identity transformation and a tunnel parameter together with the `is` operator for element identity comparison.

Comment: This is basically an art piece.  Thank you for adding the explanation on how it works.  Simply amazing!

Comment: @MartinHonnen You marked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972253/create-new-xml-for-each-repeated-node as duplicate of this question here, but OP on that question argues in the comments this answer does not solve their problem. Can you review your assessment or comment on that question as to why this answer here addresses the problem OP there says still remains?

Comment: @joanis, I think it is simply the lack of any XSLT skills of the other poster if he didn't try to adapt the code above to his input data. Obviously there is no magic sample that solves the problem of splitting data into several result documents based on a certain element in a certain document structure, the code needs to be adapted, like any sorting/grouping solution needs to be adapted. It is not that the poster made any effort to provide some code of his own for his sample, it was just another question on the same problem, only for different sample data.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I'm happy with that answer. Thank you for you comment on that answer too, I think it will help them either solve the problem or improve their question.

Comment: thank you joanis and thank you Martin for your adding. i admit i'm not an expert on xslt, this is why i asked for help in this forum, unfortunately i cannot use xslt 3 but i have only xslt 2, so i would assume i cannot fix my issue. any suggestion and help is very welcome

Comment: See the suggestions on how to adapt the code to your code sample in the comment to your question, you don't have to be an expert on XSLT but using the right pattern (e.g. `employee` instead of `FlightGroup`) and the right href expression (e.g. `href="employee-{empnum}.xml"`) for your XML structure is an adaption you should be able to make, given this question and its answer is about the same problem, only for a different XML sample structure.

Comment: Hello Martin, i did it and i published also the result editing my questions where you can see that i got 3 different xml but i have also dirty code on top, please check it out, thank you

Comment: @MartinHonnen, is it possible to select a pre-determined number of FlightGroups per file instead of just one per file?