# create new xml for each repeated node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like the following. i would create 3 new xml with the same structure and the same structure should be repeated for each eamployee tag. see below the full xml and the result i would have. i just put one xml for empnum 1001 but i would have 3 xml

```
<Syncemployee releaseID="9.2">
<ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>infor.database.connectiontest</LogicalID>
        <ComponentID>External</ComponentID>
        <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2019-09-17T09:51:03.996Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>infor.database.connectiontest:1568713863992:74:0</BODID>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>infor.test.connection</TenantID>
        <AccountingEntityID/>
        <LocationID/>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Replace"/>
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
    <employee>
        <empnum>1001</empnum>
        <fullname>John Doe                                </fullname>
        <dateofhire>2009-08-28</dateofhire>
        <lastdaterecord>2019-09-17T11:28:20.287</lastdaterecord>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <empnum>1002</empnum>
        <fullname>Jane Doe                                </fullname>
        <dateofhire>2009-08-28</dateofhire>
        <lastdaterecord>2019-09-17T11:28:20.287</lastdaterecord>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <empnum>1003</empnum>
        <fullname>Tim Bone                                </fullname>
        <dateofhire>2014-01-01</dateofhire>
        <lastdaterecord>2019-09-17T11:28:20.287</lastdaterecord>
    </employee>
</DataArea>
</Syncemployee>
```

i want to create a new xml for each repeated employee tag like below

```
<Syncemployee releaseID="9.2">
<ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>infor.database.connectiontest</LogicalID>
        <ComponentID>External</ComponentID>
        <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2019-09-17T09:51:03.996Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>infor.database.connectiontest:1568713863992:74:0</BODID>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>infor.test.connection</TenantID>
        <AccountingEntityID/>
        <LocationID/>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Replace"/>
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
    <employee>
        <empnum>1001</empnum>
        <fullname>John Doe                                </fullname>
        <dateofhire>2009-08-28</dateofhire>
        <lastdaterecord>2019-09-17T11:28:20.287</lastdaterecord>
    </employee>
</DataArea>
</Syncemployee>
```

so i want to have the result above for empnum 1001, 1002 and 1003, actually i want to have 3 xml

Dear Martin, your code doesn't work for my xml
this is the result of your transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


        infor.database.connectiontest
        External
        OnError

    2019-09-17T09:51:03.996Z
    infor.database.connectiontest:1568713863992:74:0



        infor.test.connection






    <Syncemployee>
<ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>infor.database.connectiontest</LogicalID>
        <ComponentID>External</ComponentID>
        <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2019-09-17T09:51:03.996Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>infor.database.connectiontest:1568713863992:74:0</BODID>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>infor.test.connection</TenantID>
        <AccountingEntityID/>
        <LocationID/>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Replace"/>
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
    <employee>
        <empnum>1001</empnum>
        <fullname>John Doe                                </fullname>
        <dateofhire>2009-08-28</dateofhire>
        <lastdaterecord>2019-09-17T11:28:20.287</lastdaterecord>
    </employee>


</DataArea>
</Syncemployee>
    <Syncemployee>
<ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>infor.database.connectiontest</LogicalID>
        <ComponentID>External</ComponentID>
        <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2019-09-17T09:51:03.996Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>infor.database.connectiontest:1568713863992:74:0</BODID>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>infor.test.connection</TenantID>
        <AccountingEntityID/>
        <LocationID/>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Replace"/>
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>

    <employee>
        <empnum>1002</empnum>
        <fullname>Jane Doe                                </fullname>
        <dateofhire>2009-08-28</dateofhire>
        <lastdaterecord>2019-09-17T11:28:20.287</lastdaterecord>
    </employee>

</DataArea>
</Syncemployee>
    <Syncemployee>
<ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>infor.database.connectiontest</LogicalID>
        <ComponentID>External</ComponentID>
        <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2019-09-17T09:51:03.996Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>infor.database.connectiontest:1568713863992:74:0</BODID>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>infor.test.connection</TenantID>
        <AccountingEntityID/>
        <LocationID/>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Replace"/>
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>


    <employee>
        <empnum>1003</empnum>
        <fullname>Tim Bone                                </fullname>
        <dateofhire>2014-01-01</dateofhire>
        <lastdaterecord>2019-09-17T11:28:20.287</lastdaterecord>
    </employee>
</DataArea>
</Syncemployee>
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this? If your processor supports XSLT 2.0, use the `xsl:result-document` instruction: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document

Comment: hello Michael, i'm stucked becasue i don't know how to use xsl:result-document. would you mind to help me out with my example?

Comment: @Martin Honnen, your code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57380561/split-xml-file-into-multiple-files-using-xslt?noredirect=1&lq=1 doesn't work on my case because it catches also the Syncemployee tag addition to the employee repeated tag, how can i skip the Syncemployee tag

Comment: @zanza67, have you adapted the code from that other question to your XML? Obviously there is no generic code that works magically with any XML but the problem is the same, so change any `xsl:template match="FlightGroup"` to `xsl:template match="employee"` and the `xsl:result-document href="{/Info/Campaign/CampaignNumber}-{FlightGroup-id}.xml"` to something sensible for your data like `xsl:result-document href="employee-{empnum}.xml"` and you should get the result documents `employee-1001.xml` and so on.

Comment: I have added a more generic, parameterized XSLT 3 version to the existing answer that should ease the task of adpating the code to anyone with the same problem/question but for a different XML structure and a different target element for splitting.

Comment: Please edit the question and show us the exact code you have used that, as you say, creates the wrong output. Do you get the three proper files and the additional output only as the primary result or is there the wrong contents in the files generated by `xsl:result-document`.

Comment: actually i removed the xsl:result-document command because i need an xml that contains the merge of the 3 single xml generated by your script. the xml generated has the 3 single xml created correctly but as i said in my comment it adds at the beginning some dirty text. hope this help

Comment: So your question says "i want to create a new xml for each repeated employee" and "actually i want to have 3 xml" but now you have changed your mind completely and want something else?  Nobody will be able to answer that question before you clearly state which results you want.

Comment: sorry Martin, you are right, may be i didn't expalin in the right way. what i want to achieve is this. i have an xml with 3 repated nodes (employee). i want to have an xml which has the same structure of the original but that contains just one node and this should be for each node. your code works fine except that generate dirty text at the beginning. to be clear i need this new xml in memory and not phisically but the concept is the same. so at the end of the day i will have a big xml that contains the same structure of the original but repeated 3 times each one for any employee node.

Answer (score 0):

If you repeat the "same structure of the original" several times in one result, you do not longer have a well-formed document as you then have several root elements, While that is possible in an XSLT transformation result, it is an unusual result. If you really want that kind of result then all you need to do in the approach from the other thread is to explicitly start processing with

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//employee"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

and of course remove the use of `xsl:result-document`, so the whole code would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//employee"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="employee">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="split">
            <xsl:with-param name="this-split-element" select="." tunnel="yes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="split">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template _match="employee" mode="split">
        <xsl:param name="this-split-element" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:if test=". is $this-split-element">
            <xsl:next-match/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdwrE