# Split an XML file into multiple files using XSLT if the content of an element matches

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am new to xslt and wanted to ask for your help, to see if it is possible to get the result I need.

I have a XML as seen below.

```
<CDRes xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>1111</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-21T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>a</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>1111</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-21T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>b</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>9999</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-22T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>c</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>9999</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-22T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>d</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>1111</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-30T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>x</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>1111</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-30T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>y</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows xmlns="">
</CDRes>
```

Is there a way to get differents xml files for every CDRows with the same FNumber and FDate?

For example:

file1.xml

```
<CDRes xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>1111</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-21T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>a</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>1111</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-21T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>b</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
</CDRes>
```

file2.xml

```
<CDRes xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>9999</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-22T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>c</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>9999</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-22T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>d</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
</CDRes>
```

file3.xml

```
<CDRes xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>1111</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-30T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>x</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
    <CDRows xmlns="">
        <FCD>
            <FLeg>
                <FNumber>1111</FNumber>
                <FDate>2021-01-30T00:00:00</FDate>
                <Info>y</Info>
            </FLeg>
        </FCD>
    </CDRows>
</CDRes>
```

At the moment I am trying to adapt this example,
[Split XML file into multiple files using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57380561/split-xml-file-into-multiple-files-using-xslt),
but I'm not sure if that's the correct approach.

Thanks for all the help you can give me.

Comment: Which XSLT engine are you using?

Comment: I am going to use the xslt file in a Camel route, at the moment I am testing with XSLT 2.0, but I think Camel features are 3.0 compliant as well, I have not verified this yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could group your data and then write it to file like this (untested):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="CDRes/CDRows" group-by="concat(FCD/FLeg/FNumber,FCD/FLeg/FDate)">
        <xsl:result-document href="concat(current-grouping-key(),'.xml')">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll start testing and tell you if it worked ... thanks again